# References automatically printing the respective page number in parentheses

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I would like to have references that automatically print the number of the page on which the referenced section(heading)/table/figure... happens to be in parentheses, additionally to the rest of the reference. The output should look like this for example:

`As we can see in \autoref{table}, ...` ->
As we can see in **Table 3 (S.15)**, ...

"S" stands for "Seite", "page" in german, the greatest solution would involve that the "S." automatically appears because of the `babel` package option being `ngerman`, therefore allowing this to work for every language. I'm using the `hyperref` package already because of `\autoref`. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{Section}

\blindtext

\newpage
\section{Another Section}

As mentioned in \autoref{Section}, ...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine the `\autoref` to include an `\autopageref`. Since `ngerman` defines `page` to be *Seite* and not *S.* you need to redefine it and add it to `babel` in the regular way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasngerman{%
\def\pageautorefname{S.~}}
\let\oldautoref\autoref
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{#1} (\autopageref{#1})}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{Section}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table\label{Table}}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\newpage
\section{Another Section}

As mentioned in \autoref{Section} and in \autoref{Table} ...

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Avoiding same page references

Since adding the page number to reference on the same page as the referred item is a bit annoying, you can use code adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2526/2693) to make the page reference only appear if the referred element is not on the current page:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{cPage}

\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{#1}%
\refstepcounter{cPage}\label{current\thecPage}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#1}}{\pageref{current\thecPage}}}%
  {}{~(\autopageref{#1})}}
```