# Adapting babel specific code for polyglossia in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, cross-referencing, babel, polyglossia

Using `pdflatex` and `babel` I have this code (taken from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538260/references-automatically-printing-the-respective-page-number-in-parentheses)) to redefine the way `\autoref` from the `hyperref` package prints my references, it also adds automatically the respective page number of the referenced content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasngerman{
\def\subsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} % subsection autoref -> Abschnitt ... 
\def\subsubsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} % subsubsection autoref -> Abschnitt ... 
\def\pageautorefname{S.}} % Was vor der Seitenzahl in der Klammer der Referenz steht
\let\oldautoref\autoref 
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{#1} (\autopageref{#1})} % autoref prints respective pagenumber

% No pagenumber if the reference is on the same page
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{cPage}
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{#1}%
\refstepcounter{cPage}\label{current\thecPage}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#1}}{\pageref{current\thecPage}}}%
  {}{~(\autopageref{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\section{Einleitung}\label{sec:intro}
\newpage
Text. \autoref{sec:intro}

\end{document}
```

Using `XeLaTeX` and therefore `polyglossia` instead of `babel`, how would I go about adapting this code to achieve the same output? Is it possible?

MWE (for `XeLaTeX`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{german}

\usepackage[german]{hyperref}

\addto\extrasngerman{
\def\subsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} % subsection autoref -> Abschnitt ... 
\def\subsubsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} % subsubsection autoref -> Abschnitt ... 
\def\pageautorefname{S.}} % Was vor der Seitenzahl in der Klammer der Referenz steht
\let\oldautoref\autoref 
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{#1} (\autopageref{#1})} % autoref druckt automatisch die zugehörige Seitenzahl

% No pagenumber if the reference is on the same page
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{cPage}
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{#1}%
\refstepcounter{cPage}\label{current\thecPage}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#1}}{\pageref{current\thecPage}}}%
  {}{~(\autopageref{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\section{Einleitung}\label{sec:intro}
\newpage
Text. \autoref{sec:intro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "using xelatex and therefore polyglossia" is the wrong assumption. babel works fine with xelatex too.

Comment: Ah thanks. Should I delete or edit this question? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @LinusDieLinse Well, it's up to you, but I think editing the question would be useful. I'm convinced many of the questions here about ‘how to do with `polyglossia` what can I do with `babel`’ are based on the assumption `babel` cannot be used with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use just one language, there's no need to go the `\extrasngerman` way, even with `babel`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[german]{hyperref}

\setmainlanguage[]{german}


\renewcommand\subsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} % subsection autoref -> Abschnitt ... 
\renewcommand\subsubsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} % subsubsection autoref -> Abschnitt ... 
\renewcommand\pageautorefname{S.} % Was vor der Seitenzahl in der Klammer der Referenz steht

\LetLtxMacro\oldautoref\autoref % NOT \let

% No pagenumber if the reference is on the same page
\newcounter{cPage}
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{%
  \oldautoref{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{cPage}\label{current\thecPage}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#1}}{\pageref{current\thecPage}}}%
    {}
    {~(\autopageref{#1})}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Einleitung}\label{sec:intro}

\newpage

Text. \autoref{sec:intro}

\end{document}
```

Doing `\let\oldautoref\autoref` is very risky, because `\autoref` is a “robusted” command. Use `\LetLtxMacro` instead as indicated.

I find it much better to declare all packages first, then do the settings. This helps in maintenance of the document.

I see no reason to do `\renewcommand` on `\autoref` twice, I only left the second declaration.

[image]